# Can GdPicture14 work within an Azure Function using Consumption Plan?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

We are trying to move an onprem windows service, that implements a licensed version of GdPicture14 to the Azure Cloud and into a Function using a consumption plan.

We have the appropriate license keys embedded into the software, but when we deploy to Azure, the function execution hangs (we assume it's because GdPicture, in trial mode, shows a popup that must be dismissed prior to running).

The function execution will timeout after default 10 mins, then retry another 4 times.

we also don't receive any failure messages in the Monitor section of our function app.  This is the most troubling part...  can't really see what the error is...

Can anyone tell me if GdPicture14 is compatible in an Azure Function, and what they did to get it up and running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run GdPicture on Azure Functions and on WebJobs before that, although I hadn't run v14 on the latest version of Functions on a Consumption plan.  Since I planned on doing that eventually, I setup a test project and tried it.  It worked for my simple test code (an HttpTrigger generating a dynamic 1D barcode from a number provided in the URL).

When creating the project in VS, I ensured that I selected "Azure Functions v3 (.NET Core) in the creation wizard.  I added the v14 .Net Core DLL as a reference and added my simple test code (which included a real v14 license -- as you said, no trial key or the popup will kill you).

Publishing is often where GdPicture and Functions/WebJobs have an issue.  Specialically for Functions, create a publishing profile that does NOT use Zip Deploy (uncheck the box labelled "Run from Package"). This is because usually GdPicture requires it's extra DLLs on what functions you use (the DLLs in the "Redist" dir, like filters, gdimgplug, etc).  If you use Zip Deploy, there is no way to add them to the Zip.  Then "Publish" your Function (it will say "Web Deploy").

After publishing your function, you need to FTP in to add the additional DLLs that your function might need (unless you have some super simple function that doesn't use them).  Forgetting to manually adding the DLLs is often the problem I encounter with GdPicture on Azure.  After FTPing in, change to the "/site/wwwroot/bin" directory of your function and upload the necessary DLLs.  If you are unsure which DLLs your function might use, you can safely upload all of the DLLs in the "Redist" directory.  It will ignore what you don't need. Note, there are 32-bit and 64-bit versions of each DLL.  If you know for sure that you are  running your function as one or the other (specified under Platform Features > Configuration), then you can safely just upload the one you need.  You can also upload both versions and it will use what it needs. You may be able to add these DLLs in code by manually altering the Visual Studio build config, but I haven't ever tried that.

After uploading the DLLs, restart your Function and test it.  On the portal, go to the page for your function and open the "Logs" tab at the bottom to view any output.  If you have an HttpTrigger, you can test it using the Test tab on the right side.  Hopefully this will help.

Comment: will try this and post back my results